# How to call a "JS file" by a html "button-click" and the JS file is running a bash script using shell.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bash, shelljs

I want to connect to the "server.js" file by a html-button click.

The "server.js" file is running a "bash.sh" file using shell.js

Can anyone give some ideas or directions on how to proceed?

button.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body> 

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script src="server.js"></script>

</body>
```

client.js

```
function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    }
```

server.js

```
const shell = require('shelljs');
shell.exec('./bash.sh')
```

bash.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "command 1 is running...\n\n"

mlpack_linear_regression --training_file aircon.csv -v -M lr.xml

printf "\ncommand 2 is running...\n\n"

mlpack_linear_regression --training_file aircon.csv --test_file 
predict.csv --output_predictions_file prediction.csv -v

printf "\nPredicted Output: \n\n"

cat prediction.csv # after this command the result should shown on 
                   #the browser screen


echo "hello" >> file # To test if connection is happening or not 
                     #by writing a string in a file
```

Comment: You need to use ajax

Comment: Only Ajax or anything more?

Comment: In your function `myFunction` you need to use ajax to call your backend, and excute the server.js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [shell.js](https://github.com/shelljs/shelljs). It says:

> Portable Unix shell commands for Node.js

You are trying to use it in a web browser. It is not designed to run in a web browser and will not work there.

You need to run it using Node.js.

---

You *could* write an HTTP server using Node.js, and then use Ajax (or just a regular link click or form submission) to make an HTTP request to that server to cause it to do whatever you want to so with the shell.

Comment: Can you give some links or tutorials on how to do it? :)